# Not a valid domain facebook on localhost

Tags: facebook, localhost

I cannot seem to run the facebook app on localhost. Whenever I try my domain, i get the error " App domains must match the domain of the facebook web games URL(https). Please connect these domains: localhost.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I still can't get it to work on localhost

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your facebook app domain should be from App Url.
So change your App url to - http://localhost:port_num

Will work.